# Reduce sybase sql anywhere db file size

Tags: sql, database, sybase, filesize, sqlanywhere

Is it possible, to reduce the size of an sap sql anywhere database file? After a few weeks, our database are around 10GB size, because the database does not reduce the db-size automatically. But in fact, the database only contains 240MB of data. I calculated the db-size like this:

```
SELECT  sum((((table_page_count * DB_PROPERTY('PageSize')) / 1024) / 1024)) dbsize FROM SYSTAB
```

One way should be, to unload and load the database, but that seems to be very time expensive and is not possible at runtime.

Does anyone has an idea, how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: This is off topic here, more of a DBA topic - and load/unload appears to be the only way - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43221/howto-shrink-an-sql-anywhere-12-db

Answer (score 1):

Your size calculation is missing space used by the indices, space used by row extensions and space used by the checkpoint log. The sa_table_page_usage() procedure or the dbinfo utility are better ways to calculate how much of the database file is in use, but will still not tell you how large the checkpoint log is.

To answer your question, the database file size may shrink automatically when you shut it down because the checkpoint log is dropped from the database file when the server shuts down.  However, the only way to reclaim free table/index pages to shrink the database file size is to rebuild the database.
Unless you *really* need the space, there is no reason to do this.  The database server will re-use free pages as it needs them.

Answer (score 0):

According to the accepted answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43221/shrink-a-sql-anywhere-12-database the solution is to use the dbunload command to unload/reload the database (offline, naturally). More info on this command is at http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbadmin/dbunload.html.

Another answer on that page gives this sample command line:

```
dbunload -c "UID=username;PWD=password;DBF=DB_old.db" -an "DB_new"
```

- DB_old.db is the name of the original database.
- DB_new.db is the name of the database shrunken.
- "DB_old" and "DB_new" the location of the files is relative to the path of the server that is running.
- If more than one file up the dbspace:

  ```
  DB1_old.db, DB2_old.db, ... DBn_old.db
  ```

  then it is result

  ```
  DB1_new.dbr, DB2_new.dbr .... DBn_new.dbr
  ```

Examples of connection strings are available in the dbunload reference page linked to above.

Answer (score -2):

That's how we check the size used in db at Sybase ASE:

```
select
  convert (varchar(61),o.name+'.'+i.name ) as object,
  rowtotal = convert(numeric(18,0),0),
  convert(bigint,used_pages(db_id(), o.id,indid)) * @@maxpagesize/1024 as used_pages_kb,
  convert(bigint,data_pages(db_id(), o.id,indid)) * @@maxpagesize/1024 as data_pages_kb,
  convert(bigint,reserved_pages(db_id(),o.id,indid)) * @@maxpagesize/1024 as reserved_kb
from
  sysobjects o,
  sysindexes i
where
  o.type='U'
  and o.id=i.id
order by used_pages_kb desc
```

It shows sized used by each object (means table, index etc.)

Comment: But that doesn't answer his question

Comment: Adaptive Server **Enterprise** (ASE)  SQL **Anywhere** (aka ASA) are two totally different products.